# Login failed while connecting to SQL server using MacOS terminal

Tags: sql-server, bash, macos, .net-core, terminal

I'm trying to create a Distributed SQL Server Cache table for a .NET Core project using this command:

`dotnet sql-cache create "Server=localhost;Database=CacheDb;User Id=SA;Password=Some123\!@#;" dbo DataCache`

The password is `Some123!@#`, so I'm trying to escape the special characters using `\` but it doesn't see to work as I'm getting:
`An error occurred. Login failed for user 'SA'.`

I have an image of `microsoft/mssql-server-linux` running in a docker container. The version is `Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13) (KB4466404) - 14.0.3048.4 (X64)`.

I'm able to run my web applications using that connection string (without needing to escape special characters), but I'm unable to make that connection string work using Terminal command.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You'd have the same issue on Windows - shells don't use the same escaping rules as computer languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\!` in double quote will still be `\!`. You can use single quotes:

```
[STEP 101] $ echo "Some123!@#"
bash: !@#: event not found
[STEP 102] $ echo "Some123\!@#"
Some123\!@#
[STEP 103] $ echo 'Some123!@#'
Some123!@#
[STEP 104] $
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked! 

`dotnet sql-cache create 'Server=localhost;Database=CacheDb;User Id=SA;Password=Some123!@#;' dbo DataCache`